# Problems With My Php Text to Link Conversion Function

Tags: php

I am writing a BBCode conversion function which converts plain text to hyperlink but I noticed that contents which contains well formatted links are also converted wrongly instead of being ignore. The output of the code block below gives two hyperlinks with one correct and the other wrong. How do I avoid reconverting already hyperlinked text.

```
<?php
function make_links_clickable($text){
     $prepared_str = str_replace('www.','http://www.',$text);
     $strip_double_str = str_replace('http://http://','http://',$prepared_str); 
     return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $strip_double_str); }

$strbody = "He was also the Head of Department, Environmental Health 
            in  the School of Health Technology, Orji River, 
            Enugu, and member of several professional bodies. <br/>

            Source: <br/>
            <a href='http://vanguardngr.com/2015/09'>This is Already hyperlinked</a> <br>
            http://vanguardngr.com/2015/09/buhari-appoints-abonyi-as-registrar-of-ehorecon/";

echo make_links_clickable($strbody);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string contains links that have to be transformed into html link tags. Here is a simple PHP function.

```
function autolink($string)
{
$content_array = explode(" ", $string);
$output = '';

foreach($content_array as $content)
{
//starts with http://
if(substr($content, 0, 7) == "http://")
$content = '<a href="' . $content . '">' . $content . '</a>';

//starts with www.
if(substr($content, 0, 4) == "www.")
$content = '<a href="http://' . $content . '">' . $content . '</a>';

$output .= " " . $content;
}

$output = trim($output);
return $output;
}
```

Call the above function and print it

```
echo autolink($string);
```

Comment: Just tested your script now but it still didn't leave it the hyperlink already well formed. It distorted it making it not well formatted.

There are two links in the str, one already formatted as an hyperlink while the other is a plain link text which should be converted to an hyperlink.

Your function works for the plain text but fails for the already hyperlink text.

Comment: i updated the answer with code... i tested the output...follow it now.
If it is giving correct output..Then please accept the answer

Comment: Which of the answers?
I tried testing both but it still distort the already hyperlink text. Try to run your function using the value of $strbody.

You will notice that the links breaks. Only the second link works.

Comment: Almost worked, but the link 'href' address is distorted. 
Here is what it converted the address source to:
href='<a target="_blank" href="http://vanguardngr.com/2015/09">http://vanguardngr.com/2015/09</a>

Comment: Very brilliant and neat solution. I have tested it thoroughly using various link patterns and it works perfectly. Thanks!!!

Comment: I just tried it on a large content and it failed. What could be the reason. I will post the content here:

Comment: Does above comment related any of the question

Comment: Yes, see it from my website, check the post source the link is not hyperlinked:
http://thenigeriaforum.com/p/1123/fg-to-arraign-senate-president-over-false-asset-declaration

Comment: Can you implement a regex solution. I think the problem is coming from the string explode using white spaces. Sometimes the link can be posted close to another text without really a whitespace. This instance the function will fail.

Comment: are you saying code is not working or some other problem is there

Comment: The code does not work if the link does not have a white space. For example it won't be able to convert a link like this: Read more>>http://cnn.com

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before echo

```
$strbody=strip_tags($strbody);
```

strip_tags removes html tags from string. As our text having `<a>` tag so strip_tags removes it.

Comment: Thanks Rohan Khude for trying to assist but what I want is for both links to work. I want the first link not touched by the converter as that is already well formatted while the second which is a plain text link should be converted to an hyperlink.

After trying your suggestion, I noticed that all the links were removed and that is not the result I want. I want the links.